# 8ball command in discord gives out whole list instead of one random response

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am once again asking for help with my discord bot. So i made an 8ball command, which sends a random response from a list called responses. But instead, my bot just sends the whole list. Here's my code, i hope someone can help:

```
@client.command(aliases=['8ball','magicball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *,question):
   responses = ["List of responses"]
await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(responses)}")
```

Comment: Based on your code included in your question, I have tried to replicate it and it works fine. I believe it is the way you are using your "responses" array. Would you mind editing your question and include it there?

Comment: Make sure the `responses` list is separated with commas as in `responses = ["response1", "response2", "response3"]`

Comment: Thank you @Shunya, i think it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only one "answer" has emerged in the comments, I'll summarize it again for others:

If you want to create a list of possibilities, then the individual suggestions must always be separated. This happens by a `,` in a list (`[]`). If you don't add a comma, the bot will take everything between `""`.

**Example:**

```py
responses = ["Testing, Testing1, Testing2"]
await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(responses)}")
```

Would still give out: `Testing, Testing1, Testing2`

***Changing it to the following...***

```py
responses = ["Testing", "Testing1", "Testing2"]
await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(responses)}")
```

... would give out one of the three responses: `Testing`, `Testing1` or `Testing2`.